# A Very Short Riddle

Tags: riddle

I am an object,

But why aren't I the object of your affections?

I have over 50 brothers and sisters.

Each with a home to call their own.

Yet you need do nothing to get me,

Still, none here have me.

What am I?

Hint 1:

> I am (at least in one sense), specific to the S.E. community.

Hint 2:

> My, my, you guys are slack.
>  
>  Trust the Math.SE to have my back!

Comment: An elected moderator? :-)

Comment: I wasn't aware that we didn't have elected moderators haha, and surely our mods don't have 50 brothers and sisters. But we're getting closer.

Comment: Yeah, Puzzling is still too small for elections, apparently. They're all [appointed](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators). And I was thinking of brothers and sisters in a less literal sense.

Comment: What brothers and sisters were you implying moderators had?

Comment: Their fellow moderators could be considered metaphorical siblings in our great big happy SE family. I'd imagine there's a ton more than fifty total across all the sites, though.

Comment: I consider the brothers and sisters to be on only this site. Maybe the moderators on the other servers would be the cousins. :p

Comment: brothers and sisters are exact 50? or around 50

Comment: I thought I could count them all, but I stopped at 50. Approximately back now, it's probably close to 70.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are they

> badges

long shot though

sorry, i pressed enter...and it got posted :P

reasoning...
not too strong on first two lines;

> object of not our affection : a police badge maybe?(You are under arrest)

I have over 50 brothers and sisters.

> there are more than 50 badges on community

Yet you need do nothing to get me, Still, none here have me.

> there is a badge : Tumbleweed : Asked a question with zero score, no answers, no comments, and low views for a week

Comment: What's your reasoning?

Comment: The clue says "you need do nothing to get me", but the description says "Asked a question", so that's something. Maybe the Stellar Question badge is more fitting? Oop, never mind. Guess that is what the OP was thinking.

Comment: @MikeM. You beat me at my own game! I *was* thinking of the Tumbleweed badge, but yes the Stellar Question badge does work better. In reference to the first two lines, they were mostly just fillers - you needn't work about it.

Answer (score 3):

Something like

> A coffin?

I am an object,

> Yep.

But why aren't I the object of your affections?

> I'm not dead.

I have over 50 brothers and sisters.

> There are many in a grave yard.

Each with a home to call their own.

> Each has a hole.

Yet you need do nothing to get me,

> You just need to wait.

Still, none here have me.

> Don't need one, thanks.

Comment: Ah, I almost can't fault your answer, (plus it gave me a laugh) so I'm going to be nit-picky, because this isn't the answer. 1) I am specific to StackExchange. 2) Technically you do still need to buy a coffin.

Comment: Fair enough.  Haha.  Didn't feel like a perfect fit.

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> ignorance ?

You need do nothing to get me,

> If you do nothing you have no knowledge so you have ignorance.

Yet none here have me.

> Stack Exchange sites are made to share knowledge so people here are not ignorant (or at least not totally)

Comment: Not a bad shot, but not the answer I was looking for (I have hence clarified the riddle to eliminate abstract answers like yours).

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> Joker in cards

I have over 50 brothers and sisters

> there are 52 cards in a deck

You need do nothing to get me

> There is nothing to do to get a Joker

Yet none here have me.

> Yet nobody have this.

Comment: Anyone on this site could have a Joker, this is not the answer.